# jCarousel keeps on adding new items at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I've got vertical auto scroller set up.

[edit by neuroflux]The problem occurs when I am in mode "circular" - reaching the end or the start of the carousel, it just repeats the same slide over and over.[/edit]

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {

        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl {
            direction: rtl;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
            width: 245px;
            padding: 20px 40px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
            width: 75px;
            height: 245px;
            padding: 40px 20px;
        }
        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
            width:  245px;
            height: 75px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-vertical {
            width:  75px;
            height: 245px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
            width: 75px;
            height: 75px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-vertical {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-placeholder {
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

javascript

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
            {
                // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
                carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
                    carousel.startAuto(0);
                });

                carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
                    carousel.startAuto(0);
                });

                // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
                carousel.clip.hover(function() {
                    carousel.stopAuto();
                }, function() {
                    carousel.startAuto();
                });
            };
            jQuery('#carousel').jcarousel({
                auto: 2,
                wrap: 'circular',
                vertical: true,
                initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
            });
```

Is there a reason why this do it? I've added width and height in `li` items but I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: What's the actual question?  Your title makes a statement and the content of the question just says "it doesn't work".  How does it not work?  What are you trying to do and what's happening instead?

Comment: Many carousel plugins clone the items and add them to the end when you use their circular option.  Again, explain why this is problem and what you want us to do about it.

Comment: Its internal implementation of jcarousel, as @Sparky as mentioned it clone element in circular option

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('ul#carousel').jcarousel({
    auto:true,
    scroll:1,  //this number must less than the number of list item you have
    visible:2, //this number must less than the number of list item you have
    vertical: true,
    wrap: 'last',
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
```